# JSF / Richfaces - How to set HtmlJQuery dynamically in the page

Tags: java, jquery, jsf, richfaces

I'm adding a mask into a field in my ManagedBean.

```
                htmlJQuery = new HtmlJQuery();
                htmlJQuery.setSelector("#"+perguntaVO.getCodigo() + (sequence == null ? "" : "_" + sequence));
                htmlJQuery.setQuery("mask('999.999.999-99')");
                htmlJQuery.setTiming("onload");
                htmlGroup.getChildren().add(htmlJQuery);
```

But this new mask is not evaluated in the page. It is only evaluated if I submit the page.

**What I need to do to have this jquery evaluated dynamically ?**

Comment: I've never seen the need to do jquery on the server side. Is there a reason you can't add this to the xhtml page? Remember that EL gets evaluated in the `<script>` blocks, too.

Comment: I'm creating the jsf components dynamically in the manageBean. After creating the component object I just add it to the form object that is binded inside the managedBean. Doing as shown, the <script> tag is created, but it is not attached to the inputText, because it's an ajax call. I need to know how to attach this jquery script to the inputText in an ajax request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There is no need to use richfaces Jquery object in this case.**

This line did the trick:

```
input.setOnfocus("$('"+"#form\\\\:"+componentID+"').mask('999.999.999-99').change();");
```